# Can I make Tab auto-completion case-insensitive in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion, case-insensitive

Ubuntu's Terminal uses case-sensitive auto-completion, as would be expected for Linux.

But I think sometimes it would be more convenient to use a case-insensitive one instead, to save you having to be accurate while starting a name, and would probably be worth the extra false positives.  Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: Very good question. As a usability tool, tab-completion should not be as strict as the computer system in general when it comes to naming things.

Answer (score 308, accepted):

**In order to make `bash` case-insensitive for to current user:**

Run the following shell script in a terminal:

```bsh
# If ~/.inputrc doesn't exist yet: First include the original /etc/inputrc
# so it won't get overriden
if [ ! -a ~/.inputrc ]; then echo '$include /etc/inputrc' > ~/.inputrc; fi

# Add shell-option to ~/.inputrc to enable case-insensitive tab completion
echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> ~/.inputrc
```

Start a new shell (reopen the terminal).

**To Make the changes systemwide:**

```bsh
# add option to /etc/inputrc to enable case-insensitive tab completion for all users
echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' >> /etc/inputrc
# you may have to use this instead if you are not a superuser:
echo 'set completion-ignore-case On' | sudo tee -a /etc/inputrc
```

For details, see [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1) . Yes it is a long page, but bash is a somewhat complex program, and if you want just search that page for "case-insensitive" to go to the relevant section. People usually learn bash one option at a time or one bash script at a time and it takes a long time to master all the nuances. Your interest may vary.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the user-specific/non-admin friendly solution.  The echo line seems to have worked, but now I seem to have lost the ability to use Ctrl-Left/Right to move the cursor.  Also, would `>>` be safer than `>`?

Comment: In general >> is going to be safer, my mistake, I was assuming you did not have a ~/.inputrc . I also set noclobber =) Bit sure why your arrow keys are not working, I can not replicate that. You can remove ~/.inputrc and start a new shell.

Comment: Yeah, it works again if I remove it.. According to http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/inputrc.html the new inputrc might be overriding the global one?

Comment: On my system, I can move the cursor with just the arrow keys.

Comment: @enzotib thanks, that works..  I'd like to accept the above answer, but it would be good to see this issue addressed in it.

Comment: @Matthew - I updated the command , does that work ? You now almost certainly need > rather then >>

Comment: Doesn't \n in echo require -e option?

Comment: @enzotib It does not seem to require the -e , but it does require quotes.

Comment: I still believe (after doing a test, giving the output on a single line with a literal two char sequence '\n`) that to output two lines, interpreting the `\n` as a newline, you need `-e` option to `echo`.

Comment: OK, I added -e . I think it is working without the -e as I am using zsh.

Comment: Yes, that works for me.. Sorry I'm a bit of a newbie here, but maybe it would be easier just to give two separate lines? That allows a brief explanation for the $include line.  It could also feature a check to make sure the file doesn't already exist.

Comment: Since you can also have vim mode in bash, what reason is there left to learn zsh now? ;)

Comment: I've hesitated to use this answer for a long time, though now I try it and see how simple the `~/.inputrc` configuration actually is. I would like to see a plain example of the contents of the `~/.inputrc` file rather than a shell script to create that file any day.

Comment: As long as you understand what and how the script functions, you can manually write the file if you wish. If you do not understand the script , see the comments. The comments and script were part of the explanation.

Comment: I don't think you need that if statement. `>>` will append if the file exists, and create and append if it doesn't.

Comment: Holy shit, I copied this into /etc/inputrc and I can't type "i" anymore and when I type "e" it just spams "ssssssssss[..]" into the console.. better use the solution from @emtin4

Comment: @LucaSteeb I hit that too, but then realized this whole block is not supposed to be put in your .inputrc, but typed once. Only `$include /etc/inputrc` and `set completion-ignore-case on` should be in your ~..inputrc file.

Comment: Those are commands to run not to be copy pasted into files

Comment: If you do not want to add this to your bashrc but instead only want to set it for the current session, how is this accomplished?

Comment: "source /etc/inputrc" is wrong, it should be "$include /etc/inputrc"!

Comment: @Arch Linux Tux  You broke this answer with your edit to `source` from `$include`. `.inputrc` is not a bash script!

Comment: I didn't take the answer as given, but reading `man bash` and the mini inspirational note is solving my desire for case insensitive tab-completes.C

Answer (score 72):

Open a terminal and type the below command:

```
echo set completion-ignore-case on | sudo tee -a /etc/inputrc
```

Enter password. Restart terminal.

If in some case you want to remove case insensitive, just edit /etc/inputrc file by removing the `set completion-ignore-case` line.

That's all.

Comment: OK, I clarified that for you. It takes a while to learn about bash, but keep exploring, reading, and asking. http://linuxcommand.org/ is a popular start ;)

Comment: In case there is more than one user, this changes it for all, which may or may not be the desired behavior

Comment: by far the most straight forward and simplistic answer here

Comment: simple and clear answer

Answer (score 33):

I know this question is very old but unless I am missing something I think I have a super simple solution if you are using bash.

```
echo "bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Or just add the line using your favorite text editor. Restart your bash session and enjoy.

Comment: Well, you're missing something: `~/.inputrc` is read by readline, which is what bash uses to provide this completion. Readline is also used by other programs, so, for generally setting this, `~/.inputrc` as suggested [the accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/87066/158442) would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it teaches me a little more, but I have to say that it doesn't seem any simpler than the one I accepted, which just uses an additional line to ensure the new file doesn't nullify the old.

Comment: perfect. well the only thing to remember is `bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'` should go in new line of `.bashrc`

Comment: thanks! using `bind` will be more easier to execute in a public system instead of modify any other files (`~/.inputrc`).

Comment: +1. This is the only one that works on git bash in Windows (where `bind` is necessary)

Comment: By far the easiest answer. Works perfectly in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by setting a configuration variable for GNU `readline`, which is what handles the input in an interactive shell.

The variable needed is `completion-ignore-case`, and can be set directly in your bash session with:

```
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"
```

It can be enabled for all future bash sessions by putting `set completion-ignore-case on` into the users's `~/.inputrc` file, or the system `/etc/inputrc`, to enable it for all users.  This is the initialisation file for readline.

Note that `~/.inputrc` probably doesn't exist, and if you create it, your local version will *override the system version* at `/etc/inputrc`.  The system version has lots of useful key mappings configured, such as `Ctrl-Left`/`Right`, and you have to link in the system version so you don't lose them.

The way to do this is to put the line `$include /etc/inputrc` at the top of `~/.inputrc`, e.g.:

```
$include /etc/inputrc

set completion-ignore-case on
```

Once configured, you can apply the change, either by restarting bash, or [reload inputrc](https://superuser.com/questions/241187/how-do-i-reload-inputrc), e.g. with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>.)

More information about readline and inputrc can be found in [`man bash`](https://man.cx/bash#heading28) and [`man 3 readline`](https://man.cx/readline#heading7).

Comment: When I run `man bind` in bash, I see the description for bind(2) to be "bind a name to a socket". Is that the same bind as you are using? Is there another bind?

Comment: @PeterBergman `type bind` shows it's a bash builtin, so it doesn't get its own manpage - though sometimes there may be one for a non-builtin with similar functionality.  There's some info with `help bind`, or you can search `man bash` for `   bind `.