# 's' key not working in terminal

Tags: 18.04, bash, keyboard, gnome-terminal

I was trying to make TAB auto-completion case-insensitive in Bash. So I ran the shell script as instructed in this answer : https://askubuntu.com/a/87066/880212.

And now -

- 's' - Not working
- 'copy/paste s' - Not working
- 'shift + s' - Working
- 'S' - Working

**[ This only happens in the Terminal ]**

I have looked through the keyboard settings and 's' is not mapped to anything.

This is the Output Of "xev" when I press the "s" key:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 4396015, (381,160), root:(453,287),
    state 0x10, keycode 39 (keysym 0x73, s), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 4396151, (381,160), root:(453,287),
    state 0x10, keycode 39 (keysym 0x73, s), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (73) "s"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: @Melebius . Yup, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Melebius can you please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as Helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply remove the `set completion-ignore-case On` line from the file where you added it.

According to the answer you linked, it would be either `~/.inputrc` (you can delete the file if it would remain empty) or `/etc/inputrc`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `source /etc/inputrc` line the answer instructed you to add to `~/.inputrc`. The correct line should've been `$include /etc/inputrc` as explained by the [lowest voted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081444/9016) of that question.

If you need to fix it via the terminal, you can circumvent the faulty binding of `s` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> before typing <kbd>s</kbd>.